# .NET 8 and SQL Connection Pooling

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET 8 application using entity framework connecting to SQL Server Standard using an ApplicationDbContext injected throughout the app using DI as a scoped service which means the connections are being disposed of. This is not the same thing as the answer its ben marked as a duplicate of at all.

The usage is growing and I am now experiencing these errors on busy nights. I've got until next Thursday to solve this somehow.

The queries are as efficient as they can be as far as I can tell according to SQL Profiler.

> The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

In my connection strings I have set the following, but it does not seem to have made a difference.

```cs
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=RackEmApp_live;User ID=***;***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=False; Max Pool Size=5000;"
```

From what I read, pooling is enabled by default so I shouldn't need to add anything else.

I am trying to reproduce the issue.

I have set "Max Pool Size" to be 1 and hammered an endpoint with JMeter and it responds perfectly well as if I set the Max Pool size to be 5000.

So I don't really have a good way to reliably test and iterate to see if the results are successful or not.

How can I reliably do so?

```cs
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
private readonly IOptions<Settings> _settings;
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;


public MobileController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    ApplicationDbContext context,
    IOptions<Settings> settings,
    IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
        _settings = settings;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetResult(MatchType matchType, long referenceid, string lastchecked)
{
    DateTime datetocheck = DateTime.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(lastchecked));

    Result response = new Result();
    if (matchType == MatchType.League)
    {
        response = await _context.Results
            .Where(i => i.Fixture.Id == referenceid && i.LastUpdated >= datetocheck)
            .Select(i => new Result()
            {
                ReferenceId = referenceid,
                MatchType = matchType,
                ResultId = i.Id,
                HomeFrameScore = i.HomeScore,
                AwayFrameScore = i.AwayScore,
                HomeHandicap = i.HomeTeam.Handicap,
                AwayHandicap = i.AwayTeam.Handicap,
                MatchStatus = i.Status,
                SubmitStatus = i.SubmitStatus,
                Frames = i.ResultFrames.Select(f => new Frame
                {
                    ResultFrameId = f.Id,
                    FrameNumber = f.FrameNumber,
                    HomeBreak = f.HomeBreak,
                    HomeDish = f.HomeDish,
                    HomeForfeit = f.HomeForfeit,
                    HomeLockedIn = f.HomeLockedIn,
                    HomeScore = f.HomeScore,
                    HomeDisherId = f.HomeDisherId,
                    AwayBreak = f.AwayBreak,
                    AwayDish = f.AwayDish,
                    AwayForfeit = f.AwayForfeit,
                    AwayLockedIn = f.AwayLockedIn,
                    AwayScore = f.AwayScore,
                    AwayDisherId = f.AwayDisherId,
                    Status = f.FrameStatus,
                    MatchFormatSectionId = f.MatchFormatSection.Id,
                    HomeFramePlayers = f.ResultFramePlayers
                                        .Where(i => i.HomeAway == HomeAway.Home)
                                        .Select(fp => new FramePlayer
                                        {
                                            ResultFramePlayerId = fp.Id,
                                            Number = fp.Number,
                                            ResultFrameId = fp.ResultFrame.Id,
                                            Joker = fp.Joker,
                                            HomeAway = fp.HomeAway,
                                            PlayerId = fp.PlayerSeasonTeam != null ? fp.PlayerSeasonTeam.Player.Id : 0
                                        }).ToList(),
                    AwayFramePlayers = f.ResultFramePlayers
                                        .Where(i => i.HomeAway == HomeAway.Away)
                                        .Select(fp => new FramePlayer
                                        {
                                            ResultFramePlayerId = fp.Id,
                                            Number = fp.Number,
                                            ResultFrameId = fp.ResultFrame.Id,
                                            Joker = fp.Joker,
                                            HomeAway = fp.HomeAway,
                                            PlayerId = fp.PlayerSeasonTeam != null ? fp.PlayerSeasonTeam.Player.Id : 0
                                        }).ToList(),

                }).ToList()
            })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (response == null)
            return NoContent();
    }
    return Json(response);
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```cs
namespace RackEmApp.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            // configures one-to-many relationship
            builder.Entity<Sponsor>()
                .HasOne<League>(i => i.League);

            // other configs omitted for brevity
        }

        public DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }
        // lots more db sets omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RackEmAppDB"));
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    });

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

//more stuff omitted for brevity
```

Comment: Most common is not disposing connections (no `using` or `try`/`finally` block in the code), so they are not returned to the pool until a timeout is reached.

Comment: I'm not using `using` or `try/finally` in any of my queries

Comment: @MatthewWarr Well there you go. It really is important, and you're learning why.

Comment: so are ypu saying I should use `using` statements then to improve things? The above comment said not to use them, so I'm a bit confused?

Comment: Yes, you should wrap your contexts in `using` statements, or manually `.Dispose()` your contexts in a `finally` block. Otherwise the connections do not return to the pool in a deterministic and timely way.

Comment: I've updated the question to include an example - how can I utilise it in the example?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn _"you should wrap your contexts in using statements, or manually .Dispose()"_ - it hugely depends on how context is instantiated. If it is handled by the DI (without `IDbContextFactory`) manually disposing is not only not needed but can be harmful.

Comment: As for the issue - you need to profile your queries. Connection pool is not limitless and having huge unoptimal queries which run for long time will exhaust it. For example this query potentially seems like a good candidate for optimization, for example `AsSplitQuery` might help things (based on number of joins and how they are handled). Also consider setting up `Min Pool Size` if you have burst-like load.

Comment: `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` - do you really need that? I heard somewhere that this is not the most stable feature which can also result in performance issues.

Comment: so something like `using(var context = _context) { //My logic here }`?

Comment: Where is the context being created? Please show that code. The code you showed is  not managing the lifecycle of the DbContext so it should not be calling `Dispose` or `using`. The outer code which calls this should do so. If you are using Dependency Injection the please show that.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface have updated with all I can find about it. I set this up a really long time ago and I can't fully remember how I did it, and have simply expanded upon it over time

Comment: That all looks fine.  The DbContext is a scoped service, and should be automatically destroyed at the end of each request.  Try to build a simplified repro and see if you can isolate the issue.

Comment: So the ‘using’ statements shouldn’t be necessary?

Comment: No, the context is being created using Dependency Injection, which should manage the lifetime correctly. Perhaps there is some code somewhere that manually creates a connection and doesn't dispose it.

Comment: No, everything I do in all my controllers is simply utilising _context. I don’t know how to  manually create a connection either.

Comment: @MatthewWarr please read my comments. If the issue surfaces when the load grows you need to profile your database first. Check out long-running queries, load, CPU and memory consumption. Maybe your are missing some indexes (or they need to be rebuilt) or there is just not enough resources on the server and you should add CPU/RAM. Or you have that much data so you should consider sharding. We don't have a [mre] and don't have access to your setup so you are in far better position then us to actually analyze the issue.

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron there is an example query in the question. My queries are structured similarly and I am already using sql profiler to optimise as much as possible. However the issue still remains that I can’t seem to override the connection pool size of 100. This is what the log is telling me. SQL can handle many requests and the relatively small queries I am running taking < 50ms should be no issue. It’s the quantity of concurrent users that’s killing me I think.

Comment: It’s unlikely to be server resources. It’s got 32 CPU cores and 64gb of ram. I recently doubled it to this size and the issue Persisted which is why I think the number of connections is what’s throttling things.

Comment: Have you tried setting minimum connection pool size? Please share the logs.

Comment: Also have you checked how many actual parallel requests do you have and how.long quesries take time to execute?

Comment: Which logs should I share? And how do I check the parallel requests?

Comment: Does your code use explicit database connections? Is the "repository" antipattern used anywhere? Explicit long-lived transactions don't let DbContext close the connections it creates until the explicit transaction ends. The code you posted wouldn't exhaust 5000 connections unless there were *more* than 5000 concurrent requests.

Comment: Is the application idle until it receives a 5K request wave? By default, if connections are idle for long, they're closed. If 5K requests arrive in a wave, the server may not be able to open connections fast enough. The server's caches could be empty too after long inactivity, which means the server would have to load any lookup data. You can mitigate this by specifying a `Min Pool Size` in the connection string, to prevent all connections from closing

Comment: BTW the request wave is a problem when adding a "cold" server to a far too, as the server suddenly starts receiving the same request load as the other servers in the farm. To avoid this, warmup scripts are used to make the server load any lookup data it needs, spin up enough request threads and buffers

Comment: The application will generally be in use by a few users all day, even if its only me. Then in the evenings there is a "wave" of activity which ramps up from around 7pm and peaks between 8pm and 11pm. But to be honest, I am not sure at which point it even registers additional connections or pool sizes. I'm not using s repository antipattern, I am making calls to the dbcontext directly in the controller. There are many methods/endpoints where there is multiple database calls though, but they are all using await/async